# How to set OnPageChangeListener for Multiple ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using this for loop to define my ViewPagers:

```
LinearLayout llMain;
PagerAdapter[] pAdapter = new PagerAdapter[20];
ViewPager[] pager = new ViewPager[20];   

for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
    pAdapter[i] = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
    pager[i] = new ViewPager(this);
    pager[i].setAdapter(pAdapter[i]);
    IfinAwesomePager[i].setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            //which one of my ViewPagers has been changed here?
        }
    });
    llMain.addView(pager[i]);
}
```

How do I know which one of my ViewPagers was changed in OnPageChangeListener() ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well the first question would be as to why you have 20 view pagers in the first place!

Comment: What about 3 ViewPager ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using this for loop to define my ViewPagers

That is an unusual pattern.

> How do I know which one of my ViewPagers was changed in OnPageChangeListener() ?

Create a class that implements `OnPageChangeListener`. Have that class take the `ViewPager` in the constructor and hold onto that value in a data member. Use that class instead of your current anonymous inner class for attaching a listener to the pager.

Comment: Can you please show me more usual approach to this problem?

Comment: @Bertoncelj1: I have no idea what the "problem" is. Mobile device screens are small, and so there is rarely room for more than one `ViewPager` at a time.

Comment: I not using one big ViewPager, but several smaller ones for selecting values: http://postimg.org/image/5torqte11/

Comment: @Bertoncelj1: You are certainly welcome to do so. That is an unusual pattern.