# How to set OnPageChangeListener for Multiple ViewPagers in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-viewpager

Hi I am stuck at a point where I am using two view pagers in same activity,
First one is working perfectly when I am Implimenting OnpagechangeListener. 
For second one I am making a different class to differentiate the two viewPagers but it is not working. This ques is very much similar to [How to set OnPageChangeListener for Multiple ViewPagers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895978/how-to-set-onpagechangelistener-for-multiple-viewpagers)
below is my code for the class to implement second view pager

```
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.App;

namespace Running2Win.Droid
{
    public class MyPagerIndicator : Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener{
        #region IOnPageChangeListener implementation

        public MyPagerIndicator(ViewPager vp){
            vp.AddOnPageChangeListener (this);
        }

        public void OnPageScrollStateChanged (int state){   
            Console.WriteLine("OnPageScrollStateChanged"+ state);
        }

        public void OnPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){Console.WriteLine("OnPageScrolled");}

        public void OnPageSelected (int position)
        {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 0"+position);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_one.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow_active);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_two.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_three.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                break;
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("case1"+ position);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_two.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow_active);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_three.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_one.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("case2"+ position);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_three.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow_active);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_two.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                HomePageActivity.dot_down_one.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                break;

            default:
                //                  Console.WriteLine("Default case"+position);
                //                  HomePageActivity.dot_one.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow_active);
                //                  HomePageActivity.dot_two.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                //                  HomePageActivity.dot_three.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dot_arrow);
                break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable implementation

        public void Dispose ()
        {}

        #endregion

        #region IJavaObject implementation

        public IntPtr Handle {
            get {
                return (System.IntPtr)0;
            }
        }

        #endregion





    }

}
```

from my main activity I am passing instance of the view pager in the constructor